# Recycle View android Studio search well but just shows 1 item

Tags: android-studio

Here a beginner at Android studio.
I'm creating a simple agenda app, where you can add, edit, delete and search contacts.

I used a recycle view but after adding the search option, the recycle view just shows me one contact.
The contacts are being added as appear when I search for them.
Any idea on how to fix it?
It tried changing the layout but nothing works.

My main activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/txtBuscar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listacontactos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="591dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Adapter: https://github.com/soymartanegro/agendaApp/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/agenda/adaptadores/ListaContactosAdapter.java

Main Java: https://github.com/soymartanegro/agendaApp/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/agenda/MainActivity.java

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code it's working perfectly. Please check it. Currently, I'm using dummy data for testing purposes.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/txtBuscar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listacontactos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="591dp" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**lista_item_contacto.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**contactos**

```
public class contactos {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ListaContactosAdapter.java**

```
public class ListaContactosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaContactosAdapter.ContactoViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<contactos> listaContactos;
    ArrayList<contactos> listaOriginal;

    public ListaContactosAdapter(ArrayList<contactos> listaContactos){
        this.listaContactos = listaContactos;
        listaOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
        listaOriginal.addAll(listaContactos);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_item_contacto, null , false);
return new ContactoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.viewName.setText(listaContactos.get(position).getName());
    }

    public void filtrado(String txtBuscar){
        int longitud = txtBuscar.length();
        if (longitud == 0){
            listaContactos.clear();
            listaContactos.addAll(listaOriginal);
        } else {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                List<contactos> collecion = listaContactos.stream().filter(i->i.getName().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                listaContactos.clear();
                listaContactos.addAll(collecion);
            } else {
                for(contactos c: listaOriginal){
                    if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase())){
                        listaContactos.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return listaContactos.size();
    }

    public class ContactoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView viewName, viewTelephone, viewEmail;

        public ContactoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewNombre);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Context context = view.getContext();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    SearchView txtBuscar;
    RecyclerView listaContactos;
    ArrayList<contactos> listaArrayContactos;
    ListaContactosAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtBuscar  = findViewById(R.id.txtBuscar);
        listaContactos = findViewById(R.id.listacontactos);
        listaContactos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listaArrayContactos = new ArrayList<>();
        contactos c1 = new contactos();
        c1.setName("Hello");
        contactos c2 = new contactos();
        c2.setName("Android");
        contactos c3 = new contactos();
        c3.setName("Studio");
        listaArrayContactos.add(c1);
        listaArrayContactos.add(c2);
        listaArrayContactos.add(c3);

        adapter = new ListaContactosAdapter(listaArrayContactos);
        listaContactos.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Revisar si no funciona y cambiar de lugar
        txtBuscar.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    adapter.filtrado(s);
        return false;
    }
}
```